# whats the proper way to add up coins and scores?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Whats the proper way, I've been using if statements but the way everything is set up is wrong I believe because the scores and coins are not being added up as a whole number they are being replaced by the if statements...

Example:

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {

NSString *answer = [_textbox.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
// to block user from getting incorrect answer with no text in text field
if([answer isEqualToString:@""]){

}
else

if ([answer isEqualToString:@"q"]) {
    // String is correct, resign keyboard
    _keyboard.hidden = YES;
    _textXclear.hidden = YES;
    //Perfect button
    [_closeone setHidden:NO];
    [_wrongone setHidden:YES];

    score = MAX (score +100, 0);
    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d", score]];

   coins = coins +5;
   if (score == 100) {coins = 8;}
    if (score == 0)  {coins = 0;}
    if (score == 4)  {coins = 4;}
    if (score == 3)  {coins = 3;}
    if (score == 2)  {coins = 2;}
    if (score == 1)  {coins = 1;}
    [coinsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", coins]];


}
else {
    // Was not correct.  Notify user, or just don't do anything
    [_wrongone setHidden:NO];
    score = MIN(score -5, 0);




    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d", score]];
}

if (score < 100) {
    closeonechange.text = @"Correct!";
     _imageCorP.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxg_25.png"];
} else {
    closeonechange.text = @"Perfect!";
    _imageCorP.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"telioo.png"];
}


//correct button - perfect button
}
//Perfect & Correct button sets it hidden
- (IBAction)closeone:(id)sender {
[_closeone setHidden:YES];


 }
```

Oh and I'd like the user to start with at least 50 coins before the game starts, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that as well..

Comment: As a suggestion, you should use curly braces in your if statements. `if (score == 100) { coins = 8; } else if (score == 0) { coins = 0; }`

Comment: @troop231 it's not necessary for one liners.

Comment: @MiloGosnell Not good for learning or legibility.

Comment: @troop231 okay i'll do that them, but whats the difference?

Comment: It is just a style and readability habit.  Also, it can avoid problems where someone later adds another statement to the if clause - if they don't notice the lack of braces then the statement isn't in the if

Comment: When the game starts, just set coins to 50 - `coins=50;`.  Also, I am not sure that your if statements are right - first you add 5 to coins, but then you reset the value of coins, so the addition is negated.  Did you mean to +/- coins in the if statements?

Comment: okay, well justified, About the proper way of scoring does anyone happen to know if "if" statements are the right way to set up score or is there some other way to set up score and coins to add up as the game goes alone... because right now whatever number is set in the if statements replaces the previous number for example: if the user gets 5 coins for this correct word and five points in the next word then he should logically have ten points, but thats not the case, because the label is not adding up the coins or score... Whats the proper way around this issue?

Comment: just use addition and subtraction - `coins=coins+5` or `coins=coins-3`

Comment: @Paulw11 the +five coins are what the user wins if he gets the correct answer but its not adding it to the whole number , instead it replaces the e.g. 50coins with 5!

Comment: It will depend on the score - if they score 100 then coins will be set to 8, 0 then 0 and so on.  If the score is any other value than those tested in the if statement then you should get the result of the addition (so 50+5 =55).  If your score isn't one of the values in the set of ifs and the coins aren't what you expect then you must be assigning coins= some where else.  Also have a look at the "switch" statement rather than the set of ifs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting

```
coins = 8;
```

etc. in your if statements you replace the value of coins with the new value (here: 8) - if you want to add it up you have to write

```
coins = coins + 8;
```

, like you also did for counting up the coins in the line

```
coins = coins + 5;
```

Some more tips:

You should use `if (...) { } else if (...) { }` statements instead of only using if's - by that  once an if statement is true, all others won't be executed anymore.

If you want to get rid of leading and trailing spaces of the user input you should use

```
NSString* inputText = [_textBox.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceANdNewlineCharacterSet];
```

Comment: Like this I suppose: coins = coins +5;
        if (score == 100) {coins = coins + 2;}
        if (score == 0) {coins = coins +0;}
        if (score == 4) {coins = coins - 1;}
        if (score == 3) {coins = coins - 2;}
        if (score == 2) {coins = coins - 3;}
        if (score == 1) {coins = coins - 4;}

Comment: or like this `switch (score) { case 100: coins=coins+2; break; case 4: coins=coins-1; break; case 3: coins=coins-2; break; case 2: coins=coins-3; break; case 1: coins=coins-4; break; }` . How come the penalty for getting 0 is less than the penalty for 4,3,2 or 1?  I think perhaps in the case of score=0 you mean coins=0, not coins=coins+0?

Comment: @Paulw11 exactly I'm misusing 5 points every time the user gets the answer wrong but id prefer the user gets - 2 when the score is = to 80 or below 80. right now i'm in trial and error... Xcode its a lot of fun I must admit, & addictive... one last thing though, when i -10 coins when the user presses the tip button, id like that action to happen immediately not just after the user hits the check button! hows that done?

Comment: In the code where you display the tip on the screen (where you handle the tip button being pressed) simply coins=coins-10 - you also need to update your 'coins' label.

Comment: yes but that line of code will drain the coins if the user presses it more than once, so I've added a BOOl to block it from misusing 10 more points, but how do I get the coins to update on the label immediately after the user presses the tips button?